# Is it possible to show an alert when the user tells the browser to print a page?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

A customer needs that an alert will show to the user when they try to print (either via Ctrl+P or File/Print) anything from the browser, such as "Remember to not print more than x pages" or something like that. Is it possible, using Javascript, CSS or any other approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no. You can call the print dialog from JavaScript, but you can not intercept it. 
The only way would be to do something like this would be with ActiveX on internet explorer only, which is just plain ugly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. A sort of workaround could be to open the relevant page in a separate window without menu. So the user is not able to click File->Print directly. If you want to be sure you might also capture right mousebutton and prevent the context menu from opening.

Then you will include a "print page" link with the javascript including your alert.

Not very elegant - I know.

Comment: Control-P would still be possible, though.

Comment: That's right but it should be possible to intercept that in a keydown handler `$(document).keydown(...)`

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution with window.onbeforeprint/window.matchMedia

```
function beforePrint() {
    alert('Remember print only X copies');
}
function afterPrint() {
    //do something
}

if (window.matchMedia) {
    var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
    mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
        if (mql.matches) {
            beforePrint();
        } else {
            afterPrint();
        }
    });
}

window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/FY4q2/

[**Detecting Print Requests with JavaScript**](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/)

For some reason beforeprint fires twice in Chrome though.

Answer (score 0):

however you can use css to stop printing

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
body{visibility:hidden;} or use display:none;
</style>
```

Comment: That plainly disables printing the page doesn't it?